# JS: truly secret vars (for securely submitting a score)

Tags: javascript, security, variables, anonymous-function, salt

Is it possible to find a randomly generated value declared within an anonymous function (IIFE), and if so how?

```
(function () {
  // assuming an epic, obscured, random function
  var salt = random()*10000|0;

  // assuming an event manager
  Events.on('custom event', function () {
    // do something amazing with salt here
  });
})()
```

Assuming:

- the function is loaded via ajax
- it executes on load (making it difficult to include a breakpoint)
- there's a suitably elegant solution in place to test for injection (is there such a thing?).

Comment: The client doesn't have to run your code. It can modify your code however it wants or run entirely unrelated code. It could easily just always use a salt of 0 if that's convenient for an attacker.

Comment: If you're trying to roll your own cryptography, that's a horrible idea. Cryptography is hard. There are all sorts of attacks you'll never think of; you won't get it right.

Comment: I'm really just looking for a way to obscure a variable from the global object. I can think of more then a few ways to combat injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple breakpoint in your JS exposes the salt value. It is not accessible to code outside the IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression - what you are calling anonymous function), but if you're trying to keep a debugger from seeing it via a breakpoint inside the IIFE, then JS is not going to prevent that in any way.

For example, you can set a breakpoint right where the salt value is coined and see what it is or if that code is dynamically loaded via ajax, you can set a breakpoint on the ajax loading code and then step through the loading of the code until you can then set a breakpoint where the sale value is coined.

Comment: Decided to turn my comment into an answer

Comment: cheers for the quick response. i should have mentioned, the anonymous function resides in an external script, loaded via an ajax call (jquery getScript). while the eval'ed function is available, I'm having trouble setting a breakpoint on load. is this also easy to do?

Comment: @som - it's not as easy when loaded that way, but it's still doable - just takes a little more work to get the breakpoint set.  Could also just intercept the loading of the script and modify it before it loads.  Basically, you have to decide if you're happy with obscuration (where there are obstacles in the way, but it's still defeatable) or whether you want real security.

Comment: looks likes setting a breakpoint on the xhr is the way to go. If you want to update your answer I can mark it as correct (it seems a bit vague at the moment). Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @som - more added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see to ways to hack this, first set a breakpoint and overwrite the the salt, or overwrite `Math.random` to always return the same value. And there are no ways to protect your program from this. On the other hand its very hard to find the piece of code in a minified and obfuscated script.

Comment: +1 for overriding the random function, though for arguments sake can we say I've rolled my own?